# Azure pipeline - Stage condition dependson

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have three environments: dev, hml and qa.

In my pipeline depending on the branch the stage has a condition to check whether it will run or not:

```
- stage: Project_Deploy_DEV
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev')
  dependsOn: Project_Build

- stage: Project_Deploy_HML
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/hml')
  dependsOn: Project_Build
```

I'm doing the qa stage, and I'd like to put a condition, depending on the branch, the dependson parameter will change:

```
- stage: Project_QA
   condition:
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
       dependsOn: 'Project_Deploy_DEV'
     ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'hml') }}:
       dependsOn: 'Project_Deploy_HML'
```

However, the condition above is not working, would anyone know the best way to perform this condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your YAML sample, it seems that there is a format issue. When you use if expression, there is no need to add condition field in YAML.

You can try the following sample and check if it can work.

```
stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
      - job: test
        steps:
          - xxx

  - stage: B
    jobs:
      - job: test
        steps:
          - xxx
  - stage: C
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
      dependsOn: A
    ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'dev') }}:
      dependsOn: B  
    jobs:
      - job: test
        steps:
          - xxx
```

Comment: Glad to know that it works for you. If the answer can solve this issue, you may consider accepting it as answer Thank you.