# Azure Pipeline - Stage with Multiple depends on with if condition

Tags: azure, yaml, devops, pipeline

I have a multi-stage deploy file that does validation of Bicep, then a pre-flight what-if and then the final deploy.  They all depend on a little bit of code that takes a UPN and returns the ID.  This is for the bicep file to tag the resource and add role assignments.

I am getting an error stating that the dependsOn is already defined.

I thought this would be ok as I got an answer from another Stack article ([Azure pipeline - Stage condition dependson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70406488/azure-pipeline-stage-condition-dependson)), but this does not seem to work for me.

I am very new to yaml pipelines so please forgive any apparent mistakes.

```yaml
# Deploy resources to the environment

  - stage: Deploy${{parameters.environmentType}}Environment
    displayName: Deploy ${{parameters.environmentType}} Environment    
    ${{ if or( eq(parameters.environmentType, 'dev'), eq(parameters.environmentType, 'uat'), eq(parameters.environmentType, 'prd')) }}:
      dependsOn: GetADUserUPN 
    ${{ if ne(parameters.environmentType, 'prd') }}:
      dependsOn: Validate_${{parameters.environmentType}}
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environmentType, 'prd') }}:
      dependsOn: Preview_${{parameters.environmentType}}                 
    jobs:
      - job: DeployResouucesTo${{parameters.environmentType}}
        displayName: Deploy Resources to ${{parameters.environmentType}}
        variables:
          myuserID: $[stageDependencies.GetADUserUPN.PSGetAZADUser.outputs['outputID.getUserID']] 
        steps:
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this with some help.

```yaml
  - stage: Deploy${{parameters.environmentType}}Environment
    displayName: Deploy ${{parameters.environmentType}} Environment 
    ${{ if ne(parameters.environmentType, 'prd') }}:
      dependsOn: 
        - Validate_${{parameters.environmentType}}
        - GetADUserUPN 
    ${{ if eq(parameters.environmentType, 'prd') }}:
      dependsOn: 
        - Preview_${{parameters.environmentType}}
        - GetADUserUPN                 
    jobs:
      - job: DeployResouucesTo${{parameters.environmentType}}
```