# Azure Pipeline YAML dependsOn already defined

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline that will clean, convert a VM to an image, and delete all of the resources. I would like to use that same pipeline to delete VMs without capturing an image. I can make all of the stages conditional, but when I end up with no stages that have no conditions. I keep seeing that the accepted solution to this problem is to make the dependsOn conditional as shown below. the deleteVM parameter is a boolean.

```
Parameters:
- name: deleteVM
  displayName: "just delete it"
  type: boolean
  default: false
    
- stages:
  - stage: firstStage
    dependsOn: []
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.deleteVM }}', 'false')
    jobs:
    - job: deallocateVM

  - stage: secondStage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
      dependsOn: firstStage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'true') }}:
      dependsOn: []
```

The issue is that when I do this, and try to run the pipeline with the second condition being true, it will error when parsing the pipeline: "YAML: 'dependsOn' is already defined."

P.S. I've looked at the following and they imply that the way I'm doing it is the "right" way:

- [Azure pipeline - Stage condition dependson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70406488/azure-pipeline-stage-condition-dependson)
- [Azure Pipeline - Stage with Multiple depends on with if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024637/azure-pipeline-stage-with-multiple-depends-on-with-if-condition)

Based on the comments and answers below, I have tried:

```
Parameters:
- name: deleteVM
  displayName: "just delete it"
  type: boolean
  default: false
    
- stages:
  - stage: firstStage
    dependsOn: []
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.deleteVM }}', 'false')
    jobs:
    - job: deallocateVM

  - stage: secondStage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
      dependsOn: firstStage
    ${{ else }}:
      dependsOn: []
```

Result is "Unrecognized value: 'else'. Location at position 1 within expression: else."

I have tried to use NOT EQUALS:

```
Parameters:
- name: deleteVM
  displayName: "just delete it"
  type: boolean
  default: false
    
- stages:
  - stage: firstStage
    dependsOn: []
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.deleteVM }}', 'false')
    jobs:
    - job: deallocateVM

  - stage: secondStage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
      dependsOn: firstStage
    ${{ if ne(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
      dependsOn: []
```

Result is that no matter if I put true or false, or what I put in the dependsOn in the first position, it skips this stage when deleteVM is true (I think it is ignoring this stage).

I have also tried creating a variable which I had some luck with:

```
Parameters:
- name: deleteVM
  displayName: "just delete it"
  type: boolean
  default: false

variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
  - name: dependency
    value: anActualStage
- ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
  - name: dependency
    value: '[]'

- stages:
  - stage: firstStage
    dependsOn: []
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.deleteVM }}', 'false')
    jobs:
    - job: deallocateVM

  - stage:
    - stage: secondStage
      dependsOn: ${{ variables.dependency }}
```

Result is that this will always do the opposite of what I want. no matter if I set the default value to true or false, when I set deleteVM:true, it shows "firstStage" as a dependency, and if I set deleteVM:false, it shows NO DEPENDENCY.

I get that this is interpreted at compile time and this is somewhat the behavior I'm looking for because toggling the deleteVM checkbox switches between having a dependency or not, however, it is always the wrong selection. If I continue with it doing the opposite thing I want, I can see that the secondstage runs without any dependencies (but I have to make the opposite selection of what I want). I would rather not update the verbiage to just say the opposite of what is really going on in the background and I have little confidence in this being consistent across different runs so I don't trust this enough to merge what I have for people to use.

As someone mentioned in the comment, I am using Azure Stack Hub which has very dated software and hardware limitations...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 2 if statements, use if/else. Or simply leave out the else altogether, since you're setting the depends on to an empty list.

```
- stages:
  - stage: aStage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
      dependsOn: anActualStage
    ${{ else }}:
      dependsOn: []

  - stage: aStage
    ${{ if eq(parameters.deleteVM, 'false') }}:
      dependsOn: anActualStage
```

Comment: @jessehouwing i dont think thats how it works, removing dependsOn equals = depend on the previous stage

Comment: So I tried this and when I click "validate" I am getting "Unrecognized value: 'else'. Location at position 1 within expression: else. For more help, refer to blah.

Comment: I also tried both putting an actual value instead of [] and I also tried setting the else statement to be dependsOn another stage.

Comment: are you using a very old azure devops server? docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input

Comment: yes. Yes I am... Thank you for the replies! I have not had a chance to get back to this until now. Unfortunately, I am using an older version and cannot upgrade. I was finally able to try the "if( eq(variable, 'true')" and "if( ne(variable, 'true))" and while this will run, it skips all stages (including the one that it should be running) without any explanation. I'm guessing because it's still seeing anActualStage as a dependency...

Comment: I just validated this by hard-coding the dependency  to [] and it started to run. I also tried to only one "true" if statement by setting no dependency as the result of the if statement and it didn't like it...

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure what you current code looks like and its pretty hard to figure out from your comments, if you still need help with this - you can either update the question or create a new question and post it here in the comments

Comment: I expanded the question... but the issue is simply, "If a boolean parameter is true, set "dependsOn" to [] (nothing)"

Answer (score 1):

@4c74356b41´s answer about using if-else is probably your best bet.

The way yaml works is that the `dependsOn` in your example is only really added to the "compiled" yaml file if your `if` statement resolves to true. Thus, there must be something wrong with your variables, as it looks like both of your logical statements resolves to true. I cannot really see why as it looks impossible by your example, but that is the only way I can see you getting the error you are seeing.

Comment: its actually my answer ;) the reason i'm mentioning him in my comment - is that i dont think his second way would work

Comment: Ah, I read to fast. I updated my answer.

Comment: So I tried this and when I click "validate" I am getting "Unrecognized value: 'else'. Location at position 1 within expression: else. For more help, refer to blah.

Comment: Are you running azure devops server or cloud version? If you are running server, is it up to date? The else command is fairly new, so it might not be available if you are on an older version. If that is the case, your best bet is to write two if statements which are guaranteed to be mutually exclusive, such as one being a pure negative of the other.

Comment: You can for example do "if( eq(variable, 'true')" and "if( ne(variable, 'true))" to make sure it is exclusive (using ne() instead of two different eq())

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I have not had a chance to get back to this until now. Unfortunately, I am using an older version and cannot upgrade. I was finally able to try the "if( eq(variable, 'true')" and "if( ne(variable, 'true))" and while this will run, it skips all stages (including the one that it should be running) without any explanation. I'm guessing because it's still seeing anActualStage as a dependency...

Comment: If you update the question with that code, we might be able to help more.